# Apache server httpd exiting with error

Tags: apache

Team,

I am trying to start httpd

$# service httpd start

**Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 162 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so: undefined symbol: proxy_module
                                                           [FAILED]**

Process got exiting as per above.

I am running this in RHEL 5.2 server.

I am new to httpd / apache .Please let me know how to debug this ?

Many Thanks,

-Rishal

Answer (score 1):

First place to look, make sure the following exists in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```

Remember the file mod_proxy.so must exist and contain the necessary permissions.

If it doesn't work, are you able to copy in the contents of your proxy_ajp.conf?  It maybe useful to see line 162 (and surroundings) of your httpd.conf file too .

Comment: Hi ,

I checked and "Load Module proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so" exists in httpd.conf .File mod_proxy.so exists but i am not sure whether path is set to this module .

Comment: more /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf

LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

#
# When loaded, the mod_proxy_ajp module adds support for
# proxying to an AJP/1.3 backend server (such as Tomcat).
# To proxy to an AJP backend, use the "ajp://" URI scheme;
# Tomcat is configured to listen on port 8009 for AJP requests
# by default.
#

#
# Uncomment the following lines to serve the ROOT webapp
# under the /tomcat/ location, and the jsp-examples webapp
# under the /examples/ location.
#ProxyPass /tomcat/ ajp://localhost:8009/
#ProxyPass /examples/ ajp://localhost:8009/jsp-examples/

Comment: Could you also check /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf and comment out the following if it exists:  LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so